# @media query written for max-width 420px not working for width below 320px

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have media query conditions similar showed below.

```
/* CSS for bigger than 900 */

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
/* CSS for smaller than 900 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
/* CSS for smaller than 420 */
}
```

It works fine when browser width is bigger than 900px. The media query for 900px  works fine when browser width is between 900 to 420px.. Ideally it should also work for media query 420x when browser width is anything from 0 to 420px.. However when the browser width is set 320px or lower, the media query for max-width 420px dosent work and the HTML elements are overridden with CSS ment for bigger than 900px window..

Any ideas?

Comment: Your media query is working perfectly fine even at below 320px, might be you have not changed styling under media query 420px of elements present in that query. It would be easy to check if you include all your codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you dont change styles in new media query.for example,if `h2` in `@media screen and (max-width: 900px){` get `color:green` and you dont change it in `@media screen and (max-width: 420px){`,it stay in color green.you must overlary new styles in new `media query`s.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }

  h1{
    color: green;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>I am h1</h1>
```

**In this case** ,`h1` always have color green if dont change color in `@media screen and (max-width: 420px){`